# Where does Unity save the editor window layouts?

Tags: unity

In every project there are the `CurrentLayout.dwlt` and `CurrentMaximizeLayout.dwlt` files, but those, as the name implies, are just the *current* layouts.

I've been unable to find the general files where it saves all your layouts, in order to copy it to another computer.

Where is it?

Comment: _Searching google I find all sort of questions unrelated to this specific problem._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows: %APPDATA%/Unity/Editor-n.x/Preferences/Layouts

On OSX: ~/Library/Preferences/Unity/Editor-n.x/Layouts

Where n is the major version number of the Unity Editor in question, %APPDATA% is your AppData/Roaming hidden folder in your user folder (on Windows) and ~ is your home directory (on Mac).